# Checkbox not updating in my RecyclerView when it's supposed to

Tags: android

I made a video demo of the problem here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9G4IVemayE

As you se in the video there is a checkbox in my recyclerview list item.
This checkbox needs to be checked, when the user choose to save a event to the database. But it set the checkbox to checked in the list item, when then user returns from the activity he enteres when he clicks on a item.

notifyDataSetChanged(); and recyclerView.invalidate() hasn't helped either, I have put them many different places in my attempt. The checkbox is only updated when I restart my app.

**EventActivity where the list item is shown and saved from:**

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_saveToDb:
            DbHelper.getInstance(EventActivity.this).saveToDb(eventID, title, description, subtitle, start, end, 1, url, imgURL);

      //1 in the parameters means that it shall have a checked box. 0:unchecked

            MainActivity.databaseList.add(new Event(eventID, title, description, subtitle, start, end, url, imgURL, 1));
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
            //this checkbox is for an activity layout. nevermind it.
            break;
  }
}
```

**This is in MainActivity:**

```
// I have tried to call this method different places.

     public void initRecyclerView(List<Event> list) {

    rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(list, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
    rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

**From the RecyclerView Adapter class where i set the checkbox if 1 or 0 **

```
 @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(list.get(position).getIsDb() == 1){
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

**The whole MainActivity class:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    showListPref = preferences.getInt("SHOW_LIST", 3);

    databaseList = new ArrayList<>();
    jsonList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Vi loader dataen fra start af, så de er klar til at vises frem når som helst og hurtigt
    loadDatabaseData(this);
    new JsonParser().execute();


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_location_city);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("  Events in Aarhus");


/*
   Sørger huske den valgte liste efter appen er lukket og vise den valgte igen når appen åbnes igen
   og sætter også titlen på toolbaren efter hvilken database der vises.
    */


    if (showListPref == 2) {
        initRecyclerView(databaseList);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("  Events in Aarhus (Database)");

    } else if (showListPref == 3) {
        initRecyclerView(jsonList);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("  Events in Aarhus (JSON)");

    }
}


/*
     Her loader vi de data der er gemt i databasen og gemmer dem i List<Event> databaseList.
     databaseList bruges til adapteren for recyclerviewet så dataen fra databasen kan vises i recyclerviwet.

      */
public void loadDatabaseData(Context context) {

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null);
    EventCurserWrapper wrapper = new EventCurserWrapper(c);

    checkID = new ArrayList<>();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            databaseList.add(new Event(wrapper.getEvent().getEventID(), wrapper.getEvent().getTitle(), wrapper.getEvent().subtitle, wrapper.getEvent().getDescrption(), wrapper.getEvent().startTime, wrapper.getEvent().endTime, wrapper.getEvent().url, wrapper.getEvent().getImgURL(), wrapper.getEvent().isDb));
            checkID.add(wrapper.getEvent().eventID);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    c.close();

}


/*
Denne metode bruger list parameteren til at skifte mellem de forskellige
lister når man fra menuen på toolbaren vælger om man vil se events fra JSON eller Databasen.
 */
public void initRecyclerView(List<Event> list) {

    rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(list, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
    rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


/*
Async task bruges her til at loade json data og gemme dem i en arraylist
og køre asynkron med appens "mainthread".
 */
private class JsonParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LOADING DATA FROM API", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            url = new URL(URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;


                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                return (result.toString());
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        try {

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray events = object.getJSONArray("events");

            for (int x = 0; x < events.length(); x++) {
                JSONObject object1 = events.getJSONObject(x);

                String eventID = object1.getString(EVENT_ID);
                String title = object1.getString(TITLE);
                String subtitle = object1.getString(SUBTITLE);
                String description = object1.getString(DESCRIPTION);
                String url = object1.getString(EVENT_URL);
                String imgURL = object1.getString(PICTURE_URL);


                JSONArray dateArray = object1.getJSONArray(DATES);
                for (int y = 0; y < dateArray.length(); y++) {
                    JSONObject dateObject = dateArray.getJSONObject(y);
                    long start = dateObject.getLong(START);
                    long end = dateObject.getLong(END);

                    if (!title.isEmpty()) {


                        /*
                        Da datoen vi får fra JSON er i UNIX/Epoch format, så
                        konverter vi denne dato til rigtig "kalender" dato med koden nedunder
                         */
                        Date date = new Date(start * 1000);
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
                        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                        String startdate = format.format(date);

                        Date date2 = new Date(end * 1000);
                        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
                        format2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                        String enddate = format2.format(date2);


                        /*
                        Her tjekker vi om de events der netop bliver loaded fra JSON om de i forvejen
                        eksister i databasen og hvis de gør, sættes flag til 1 og denne værdi bruges
                        i adapteren til at sætte checkboxen til true : 0 = false;
                         */
                        int flag = 0;
                        if (DbHelper.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getEventIDs(eventID).contains(eventID) == true) {
                            flag = 1;
                        }

                        jsonList.add(new Event(eventID, title, subtitle, description, startdate, enddate, url, imgURL, flag));

                    }
                }
            }


            rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, events.length() + " events loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.listfragmentDemo:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityTest.class));
            break;

        case R.id.menu_showDatabase:

            preferences.edit().putInt("SHOW_LIST", 2).apply();
            initRecyclerView(databaseList);

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Events in Aarhus (Database)");
            break;

        case R.id.menu_showJson:

            preferences.edit().putInt("SHOW_LIST", 3).apply();
            initRecyclerView(jsonList);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Events in Aarhus (JSON)");
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/*
OnResume kaldes i stedet for onRestart, da vi kan være sikker på kaldes i activitens lifecyclus
som du engang fortalte på tavlen (;
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

**The whole adapter class for RecyclerView:**

```
public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static List<Event> list;
private static Context context;

public RvAdapter(List<Event> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.eventTime.setText("START:  " + list.get(position).getStartTime() + "      END:  " + list.get(position).getEndTime());


    /*
    Hvis eventet eksisterer i databasen (1) så sæt checkboxen =true
     */
    if(list.get(position).getIsDb() == 1){
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

     TextView title, eventTime;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_event_title);
        eventTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_event_time);
        checkBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_event_checkbox);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("EVENT_ID", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getEventID());
        intent.putExtra("TITLE", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("START", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getStartTime());
        intent.putExtra("END", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getEndTime());
        intent.putExtra("DESCRIPTION", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDescrption());
        intent.putExtra("SUBTITLE", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getSubtitle());
        intent.putExtra("URL", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl());
        intent.putExtra("IMG_URL", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImgURL());
        intent.putExtra("isDatabase", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getIsDb());
        intent.putExtra("POS", getAdapterPosition());

        context.startActivity(intent);



    }
}
```

}

Comment: where do you call initRecyclerview?

Comment: initRecyclerview is called when the user choose to switch between two list in the app. a List loaded with json data and a list loaded from the database in the phone. based on the list choosen i change the list parameter. @NongthonbamTonthoi

Comment: Post you mainactivity code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in a single line: `MainActivity.jsonList.get(position).setIsDb(1)`;

I get the position of the clicked item with intentExtras: `position = getIntent().getIntExtra("POS", 0);` in the EventActivity where an event is shown after a click on a liste-item

and use that position to update the isDB variable of the model data.
Then onReturn to MainActivity I just call: notifyDataSetChanged();

the isDB variable is updated to 1 inside here after I save to the database.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {


        case R.id.menu_saveToDb:


            DbHelper.getInstance(EventActivity.this).saveToDb(eventID, title, description, subtitle, start, end, 1, url, imgURL);

            MainActivity.databaseList.add(new Event(eventID, title, description, subtitle, start, end, url, imgURL, 1));

            //Update isDB of the current model data for the seleceted list_item
            MainActivity.jsonList.get(position).setIsDb(1);

            //This is for another checkbox. nevermind it
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
            break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating boolean value in db but your model item in Main Activity is not updated since RecyclerView is already instantiated.

There are several methods to solve this:

- Reload RecyclerView data model in MainActivity onResume method.
- Notify from EventActivity to MainActivity the change and update item in RecyclerView (class LocalBroadcast manager can help you in this) (**BEST APPROACH**)
- Always read from db to get updated bool value (in method -> list.get(position).*getIsDb()*) (**WORST APPROACH**)

Comment: By reloading the RecyclerView data model. Should I just call the method initRecyclerview in onResume?

Comment: Yes, but first you have to update your data model, otherwise RecyclerView adapter refresh the old values and nothing change. Can you post code of MainActivity and adapter?

Comment: Here you go.  At the bottom of the question i posted the whole class you requested. I think were you need to look is where i say this in asynch task: jsonList.add()

Comment: The problem is databaseList variable, it's filled in method loadDatabaseData only at first time. You need to call loadDatabaseData in onResume method, (you can also remove it from onCreate) and then notify adapter with updated databaseList

Comment: I have solved it! (:
It's a little sneaky solution, I'will post it